# Other than session state what else in an asp.net application would use up server RAM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, ram

If I had 2 million users I've cached 1 mb's of data shared between all those users what else would use up RAM that each user would create?

EDIT: 
2 million users login and have sessions at the same time, they are all making requests - maybe 10 requests per second. They are retrieving, for example, random numbers using a random number generator.

Comment: 1 MB for two million users?  As in, one nibble per user?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking:  are you asking what things that would be created by users would use up RAM?

Comment: no, the cached data is shared apparently

Comment: @AnnL yes that is what I am asking

Comment: This is very vague question... even 100M users will not cause any server side usage if they don't make any requests... And if your server is purely stateless there still will be no per-user cost...

Answer (score 0):

There is overhead for each request in a web application. It starts at the socket and works it's way up through IIS to ASP.NET to your application.  You should look into performance monitoring.  You can learn all sorts of neat things.  Here is a good link for that:

[How to Measure Memory Usage for a Live ASP.NET MVC Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681790/how-to-measure-memory-usage-for-a-live-asp-net-mvc-web-application)

Comment: Thanks Jake, I am asking specifically about RAM overhead. What would be stored in memory when a request is made?

Comment: Also, thanks for the link I however don't actually have a number of users to test how much memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is look at your process yourself.  Take a memory dump (using procdump or taskmgr) and then analyse it with windbg.  This will show you exactly what is in memory on each heap and how much of it there is:

A good place to start is with the sos command [!dumpheap -stat](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/25/496973.aspx)