# IIS Memory Leaks - Session size

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, memory-leaks

I am trying to trouble shoot a memory issue with our web application.  Using the SCOM tools I see that our application is using 5.8 GIGS of memory.  This happens on our production server which I cannot access.  It is not happening in DEV and TEST (probably due to usage).

I suspect this has to do with the objects on the session.  Is there a way to tell how much total memory our session is using?

Can you give me tips for pinpointing where the memory leaks are coming from?

I am not using Interop or any unmanaged code – that I know of. 
The is an ASP.Net 4 web application running on IIS7.

Comment: How long is your session timeout set to? Are you storing anything in ApplicationState?

Comment: I am new to the project.  I see some use of ApplicaitonState but not a lot.  The session use is excessive.
The session timeout is set for 30 minutes.

I don’t like using this much session and I think that is the problem.  But I need a way to pinpoint it for management – or prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Give these links a look:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1776025.aspx/1

[How to measure memory usage for a Live ASP.NET MVC web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681790/how-to-measure-memory-usage-for-a-live-asp-net-mvc-web-application)

And possible reasons your application may be using a lot of memory:

[ASP.NET Website Memory Usage quite high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405557/asp-net-website-memory-usage-quite-high)

Comment: Another option, but maybe not the best since the problem only presents itself on Production, is to enable Session State to be stored in SQL Server. If memory usage decreases then you can assume that Session state is the problem. If session state is used extensively it's most likely the issue, especially if you have a lot of people visiting the site.

Comment: I take it from the responses that there is no way tell how much memory is dedicated to the session.  Is this correct?

Comment: We have noticed that the memory usage does not go down.  It increases to about 6 GIG in about and hour and then stays that high.  It stays that way overnight when usage is very low.  It seems that memory is never released.

Comment: The problem may not be Session state then. If your session timeout is set to 30 minutes, then all the session objects should be GC'd after that period of inactivity. You would see a decrease in memory as those sessions fall off. What process are you checking and how are you checking it for memory usage?